# MAMP MySQL Connection Error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, database-connection

I deleted a database that I dont use  from my PhpmyAdmin panel,after I deleted it,my localhost gave an error and I cant to access to the phpmyadmin anymore :(

When I write mysql to my terminal it gives an error like this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: This is something worse, then the result of DB removal

Comment: What database did you delete? Was it `mysql`?

Comment: yeah it is mysql I connected w'th MAMP server

Comment: Zafer-MacBook-Pro-2:~ zafer$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: how can I do with terminal commands_

Comment: try "mysql -h localhost -u [username] -p" what response do you get?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear there; was the deleted database named `mysql`? Because that's the one with all the users and permissions

Comment: no I just deleted a database for example "userdata" from mysql

Answer (score -1):

i think you have deleted the files of sql that belong to the phpmyadmin. and please post details to you question.